# USB-Ethernet Adaptors and Power over Ethernet (PoE)

Tags: networking, usb, ethernet, power-over-ethernet

I have a [LeMaker HiKey](http://wiki.lemaker.org/96boards/HiKey) and I'm having trouble getting the network running in a preferred configuration. The HiKey is an inexpensive ARM64 development board running [Linaro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linaro). Linaro is a lot like Debian with an LXDE desktop, and in effect, this is a mini-desktop with an ARM CPU architecture.

The board is powered and has two USB ports and a micro USB port. However, the board [lacks an ethernet port](http://wiki.lemaker.org/HiKey%28LeMaker_version%29:Hardware_specification). The USB ports do not power attached devices, so I need to use a powered hub when using them.

*If* I use an Ethernet-to-USB adapter *with* a powered hub, then the device has network connectivity. *If* I remove the powered hub and provide [Power over Ethernet (PoE+)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_over_Ethernet) to the Ethernet-to-USB adapter, then the device loses its network connectivity.

I tried 3 different Ethernet-to-USB adapters with the same results, so I am missing something. I think this is a case of me not knowing what I don't know. Can anyone explain to me what I am missing in the configuration using Power over Ethernet?

(I am trying to avoid a PoE injector in the adapter. That is, I don't want to have to plug the Ethernet-to-USB adapter into a wall socket. Its the reason I purchased a Power over Ethernet switch).

Comment: are you using a POE splitter too?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_over_Ethernet#/media/File:ZyXEL_ZyAIR_G-1000_and_D-Link_DWL-P50_20060829_2.jpg   Notice the device that gets powered doesn't get powered over ethernet.  Power seems to come out of the ethernet socket, through an ethernet cable, goes to a splitter which has a regular ethernet with a power cable, and those plug into your device that device that requires ethernet and power separately.

Comment: @barlop - No, there is no splitter.

Comment: Does the USB -> Ethernet adapter work correctly when directly connected to the board without using a hub (I'm taking the word hub to mean a USB hub, I'm not sure though)? I've only ever seen USB -> Ethernet adapters that are USB bus powered. Can you provide a link to your USB -> Ethernet adapter?

Comment: this may be a good usb ethernet adaptor. The anker usb-ethernet adaptor. . Somebody recommended it to me once saying it had a good chipset and i think they said it was back compatible with usb2 and from what i recall, it was. No external power required.

Comment: @Jonno - no, a direct connection does not achieve network connectivity. The line definitely needs power.

Comment: Ah I think you're saying the usb doesn't have a socket for external power.. but it works in a hub.  Well how about without a powered hub but also without power over ethernet?    And how about getting a splitter adaptor and just passing the regular ethernet to the usb-ethernet adaptor. It may be that power over ethernet going straight into a device could damage the device 'cos it's not meant ot have power going into it through an ethernet cable.  And maybe your computer is giving a voltage or current thati s too low.. maybe too low a voltage to the stick. you could test that.

Comment: the usb charger doctor http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/USB-Charger-Doctor-Current-Voltage-Charging-Detector-battery-Voltmeter-Amp-/301704409564?hash=item463efbf1dc:g:vzcAAOSwLVZVwHLE    shows usb volts and amps  Good for diagnosing issues of volts and amps with usb.

Comment: @barlop - *"Ah I think you're saying the usb doesn't have a socket for external power..."* - Yes, the board is powered, but the USB ports need external power. The board does not provide power to the ports. I added it to the question.

Comment: I'm suspicious that your best bet is going to be a PoE splitter as @barlop has suggested, allowing your PoE to carry the power, but an additional cable going to your USB hub. I doubt there will be a solution for such separate technologies to power each other (PoE to Ethernet to USB to USB Hub). In fact, thinking about it further, if the PoE was responsible for powering the USB -> Ethernet adapter and you plugged that into a powered hub, it'd likely go pop. I'd imagine the USB -> Ethernet adapters are built to explicitly get their power from the USB hub so only one device is responsible.

Comment: If a USB port doesn't have it's own power, you can't give it power via a USB-to-Ethernet card, since that card expects power at the USB side, and can't accept power at its ethernet side. As others have said, you need a specialized device that will accept PoE on one end, and spit out another network jack and a power jack for your USB hub.

Comment: @cloneman - maybe that's what I don't quite understand... I thought a powered USB hub supplies power to the ports. But thinking about it, a powered hub supplies power to the powered devices (and not the USB ports on the computer). In effect, maybe I need the USB side of the Ehternet-to-USB adapter to tap from the PoE. That is, the converter is just a powered device. Would you know the marketing term manufacturers call the feature?

Comment: I think it's called a PoE Splitter. You would use it as the power source for your powered USB hub. The objective being, not having to plug your USB hub into the wall.

EDIT: http://www.amazon.co.uk/Foscam-Splitter-Adapter-802-3af-compliant/dp/B00CDT7KPO/ref=pd_pgd_B0038JOWF4_B00CDT7KPO?pf_rd_p=801669007&pf_rd_s=product-alert&pf_rd_t=201&pf_rd_i=B0038JOWF4&pf_rd_m=A3P5ROKL5A1OLE&pf_rd_r=1S4XRPBRYCZ98ERW1HRZ

Comment: @jww I have no idea what kind of usb ports you think you have but a USB port provides power.The reason why a usb hub takes a power source, is because if u have lots of devices then the current gets split and may be too low, so the power src helps when there r many devices or when a device needs excessive current.A power source would be what powers usb ports of a hub(and it can get power from the computer's usb port), n power goes from the ports, to power devices.   A computer's USB port is provided power from the computer's power supply, and provides power.All USB ports send power out of them

Comment: @barlop USB ports don't always provide power onto the USB bus. I'm pretty sure the USB spec doesn't require it, but even if it does, there are millions of devices out there that have USB Type A (host) ports, but don't provide power to the bus. Especially small cheap embedded devices like OP's, where they like to save money and thermals on the power supply by only spec'ing the power supply to power the board itself, not a beefier power supply that can provide power to USB devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For PoE to work, both ends of the Ethernet link carrying power need to support the same flavor of PoE. I've never seen a USB Ethernet adapter that supports receiving (acting as the "powered device" (PD), not the power supply for) any flavor of PoE.

I doubt a PoE-receiving USB Ethernet adapter exists, because PoE is thought of as a way to power whole remote embedded devices, not just their NICs, and I don't think there's a commonly implemented way for a USB *device* to power a USB *host* (not until USB type-C, that is).

So you won't be able to make this work until/unless you find a USB Ethernet dongle that is designed to act as a PoE receiver for the same flavor of PoE as your PoE-supplying hub/switch/midspan power supply (power injector/splitter) supplies.

Comment: Thanks Spiff. The frustrating thing for me is the board is headless. I SSH into it. The only USB connection is Ethernet and it appears to need power. If the damn adapters would tap PoE for power instead of looking for it on the USB side, then all these troubles would go away.

Comment: @jww I feel like I could help you better if I understood your constraints. How does the HiKey board get power? If it already uses a wall-wart power supply, why can't you plug a small self-powered (meaning, one that uses its own power supply, as opposed to "bus powered" ones that have to receive power from the USB bus) USB hub's wall-wart power supply into the same outlet? Also, since you already have a PoE switch to act as the PSE (Power Supply for Ethernet; the power injector), couldn't you just use the "receiver half" of a standards-compliant PoE splitter to power your self-powered USB hub?

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking for a similar device that would let me do this without an ethernet adapter, a PoE usb splitter and a Y-cable and this is the closest I've found so far. It uses USB-OTG to connect the ethernet adapter directly to the device while also providing power.

- http://concinnity.eu/Products-English/LAVA-Solution-Enablers/STS-PE-USB-Ethernet-Adapter-with-PoE/
- https://www.uctronics.com/tools-and-accessories/pi-accessories/uctronics-poe-adapter-to-micro-usb-ethernet-power-for-raspberry-pi-zero-fire-tv-stick-chromecast-google-mini-and-more-ieee-802-3af-compliant.html

And a similar solution for USB-C+PD:

- https://shop.poetexas.com/products/gat-usbc-pd-1